# The number roots of $x^2=100^{\sin x}$ in $[2\pi;3\pi]$

Tags: calculus

I could prove that the equation $x^2=100^{\sin x}$ in $[2\pi;3\pi]$ has at most three solutions in $[2\pi;3\pi]$, but I need to find the number of solutions exactly. I guess it has three solutions in $[2\pi;3\pi]$, but I could not prove? How do we prove this?

Comment: It seems that there is only two roots : [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+x^2-100^%28sin%28x%29%29+from+x%3D2*pi+to+3*pi)

Comment: And from the graph, it is easy to see that a way of approaching it is to show that $100^{\sin x} $ is increasing from $2 \pi $ to $2.5$ pi and decreasing from $2.5 \pi$ to $3\pi$, hence has 1 solution in each of the regions.

Comment: Take logs, the behaviour of both sides is familiar in the domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking logs, we must have  $ \log_{10} x = \sin x $

Now in $[2\pi, 3\pi]$, LHS is strictly increasing, and we can note $0 < \log_{10} {2 \pi} < \log_{10} {3 \pi} < 1$

The RHS in the same domain goes from $0$ to $1$ (when $x = \frac{5\pi}{2})$ and back to $0$.  As both LHS and RHS are continuous, RHS must cross the LHS twice, once when it ascends, and the second time when it descends.